# SWFLoader/ApplicationDomain: scaling problem when using a new domain on the loaded application

Tags: apache-flex

When loading an Application (spark.Application) as a SWF in another Application using SWFLoader without preserving the domain, the scaling of the first application gets scrambled.

Examples are below:

App1.mxml

```
<s:Application width="100%"
               height="100%"
               xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private static const LOADER_CONTEXT:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain());
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:SWFLoader width="100%"
                  height="100%"
                  source="App2.swf"
                  loaderContext="{LOADER_CONTEXT}" />
</s:Application>
```

App2.mxml

```
<s:Application width="100%"
               height="100%"
               xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:Panel width="100%"
             height="100%"
             title="Panel" />
</s:Application>
```

When not using LoaderContext in App1.mxml scale is OK. When using it, App2.mxml is scaled. I tried to set scaleContent=false in SWFLoader but then the loaded application only occupies a fraction of the screen (600x400 or something like that).

Any help or suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: have you ever found the solution to this? facing the same prob.

Comment: 2018, same problem lol